# Only one principal(user) can be created by role attribute which is enum + rails

Tags: html, ruby-on-rails, ruby, devise

i am new to rails and creating a school app where i have given an attribute role to user which is deciding the role of user and i want to create only one user can be principal(role), how do i achieve that there can not be create more than one principal user in app,
i am using devise for authentication...

i tried this =>
validates :role, :uniqueness => { :role => "principal" }

but it is restricting me from creating any kind of user , in my user enum i have given 4 roles [admin,principal,teacher,student]

any help or advice will be appreciated.... thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would use a [custom validation](https://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_validations.html#custom-methods) like this:

```
validate :one_principal_exists

private

def one_principal_exists
  return unless principal?
  return unless User.where.not(id: id).exists?(role: 'principal')

  error.add(:role, 'already exists')
end
```

The idea is to check first if the current user is a principal, if not skip the validation. And then check if there is already another user (who has a different id than the current user) in the database who has the principal role. If such a user exists, then add a validation error to the role attribute.

Please note that you might need to add more conditions to the database query when you, for example, want to support multiple schools and each school has a different principal.

Comment: thank you so much @spikermann sir it works fine...thank you for your guidance in right way

Answer (score 1):

in model use below code

user.rb

```
before_create :check_principle


def check_principle
  if User.find_by(role: "principle")
    errors.add(:code, "principle already exist")        
    return false
  end
end
```

Comment: no it is not restricting to create new one "principal <= in my case" it is committing another user with principal role????

Comment: you tried above validation?

Comment: yes sir, i have tried but unfortunately it is not working.... thank you for your help :-)

Comment: Would you mind fixing spelling mistakes, especially in code examples instead of telling the reader to _"ignore spelling mistakes"_? There is, for example, no `befor_create` method, and `find` expects an id, but not a hash. Unexperienced readers might not be that familiar with Ruby or Rails methods and their syntax and therefore they might not be able to understand the errors and their meaning that are generated by the code in your answers.

Comment: yes @spickermann sir , i have faced that errors early of befor_create and error.add too, and there for i correct them but Divyaraj Solanki sir's code is unable to restrict by creating another principal(user) but by the way thank you both of you for your time and help ,appreciated thanks :-}

Comment: @spickermann I need your little help. I want to show a typing indicator with action cable in rails. can you suggest me any video or tutorial